# Input string not in correct format c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have a stored procedure in my database which I am execting with the below code. I am passing in a parameter to this stored procedure and when the data is returned and it is read in the while loop I get an input string not in correct format exception even tho i hard code a value into the query parameter.

```
var response = DataAccessBridge.IADODao.CommandWrapperSelect<List<FeaturePack>>(command =>
        {
            var result = new List<FeaturePack>();
            const string storedProc = "dbo.usp_PSTN_GetFeaturePacks";


            // Add the input parameter and set its properties.
            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
            parameter.ParameterName = "@FeaturePack";
            parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            parameter.Value = featurePackId;

            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            command.CommandText = storedProc;

            var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                result.Add(new FeaturePack
                {
                    FeaturePackId = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["featurePack"].ToString()),
                    FeatureId = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["featureId"].ToString()),
                    Description = dataReader["Description"].ToString(),
                    AlwaysOn = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["alwaysOn"].ToString()),
                });
            }

            return result;
        });
```

Above is my code which executes the stored proc and adds the parameter and in the while loop I receive this exception. can anyone give me any clue why this is being thrown?

The

```
featurePackId
```

parameter is hard coded in this example to 1 and i still receive this error.

Comment: What is the data type returned by the procedure for `featurePack`, also what is the type specified in proc for the parameter. May be you are getting `null` back, check it with `DBNull.Value`

Comment: What line does the exception occur at? When you step through the code, what value do you see for the string?

Comment: if you debug that while loop you will be able to see the value that causes the issue and it should be clear from that what the cause is. Or set to break when the exception is thrown: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx. We can't guess at what data is returned, but you can see it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok, I deleted as after looking, I don't know that my 'sub question' made sense (it was starting to not make sense to me and I asked it xD)- and now your response makes no sense (makes sense but no context so seems random) because my question is gone- doh! sorry but thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't told us, you're almost certainly getting the exception on one of these lines:

```
FeaturePackId = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["featurePack"].ToString()),
FeatureId = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["featureId"].ToString()),

AlwaysOn = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["alwaysOn"].ToString()),
```

and it will be because the value for one of the rows cannot be converted to an integer. You should debug the code to find the row it is failing on and see what the values of the columns `featurePack`, `featureId` and `alwaysOn` are for the row that is failing. One of them will not be an integer value.